# React redux thunk return dispatch not called

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am developing a web application which I would like to use react redux. but my app is not dispatching. If I want to careate a new project and send request to action to dispatch it does not dispatch.

```
class CreateProject extends Component {
state = {
title: '',
content: ''
}
handleChange = (e) => {
this.setState({
  [e.target.id]: e.target.value
})
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
// console.log(this.state);
this.props.createProject(this.state);
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="container">
    <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create a New Project</h5>
      <div className="input-field">
        <input type="text" id='title' onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <label htmlFor="title">Project Title</label>
      </div>
      <div className="input-field">
        <textarea id="content" className="materialize-textarea" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
        <label htmlFor="content">Project Content</label>
      </div>
      <div className="input-field">
        <button className="btn pink lighten-1">Create</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
)
 }
```

Projectreducer.js

```
const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
    console.log('create project', action.project);
    return state;
  
  case 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR':
    console.log('çreate project error', action.err);
    return state;
  default:
  return state;
     }
    };
   export default projectReducer;
```

I have consoled on the function on project action is show the item on the console.
When I try consule of the return statement nothing happens
projectAction.js

```
export const createProject = (project) => {
return { type: 'CREATE_PROJECT', project }
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
  make async call to database      
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  console.log(firestore);
  firestore.collection('projects').add({
    ...project,
    authFirstName: ' nm',
    authorLastName: 'kjbbggh',
    authorId: 12345,
    createdAt: new Date()
  }).then(()=>{
    dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT', project });
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch({type: 'ÇREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err})
  })
}
};
```

Comment: You may have an error in your call to the firestore. Try console inside the catch. Also you may want to use the firestore date type, this can prevent confusion
`firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate` Here is the date example from the docs:
`dateExample: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815"))`

Comment: @Michael I have tried that it did not work.The return is work called at all. I have tried console in the return but nothing displays